# Problems with [] (square brackets) with userId in OracleConnection

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm trying connect to Oracle database with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library but the user includes square brackets. The problem is that always send me Oracle exception ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied.

With SQL Developer works perfect.

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v18.6.0 and
.NET Framework 4.7.2

The others parameters, like pass and host are correct, I'm sure. I tried with another user that doesn't has square brackets and works well.

My code looks like this:

```cs
using (var conn = new OracleConnection(SERVER, new OracleCredential("myId[SERV]", secPwd)))
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: With connection string I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [proxy user authentication](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/proxy-users-and-connect-through)

"myId" is your proxy user,   "SERV" the database user

check [here](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/ProxyUserConnection.html) how to connect with proxy user in .net

basically there are two possibilities:

```
  new OracleConnection("Data Source=ORA; User Id=my_proxy_user; Password=my_proxy_user_password;")
```

or

```
 new OracleConnection("Data Source=ORA; Proxy User Id=my_proxy_user; Proxy Password=my_proxy_user_password; User Id=scott;")
```

Similar question on [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195399/oracle-connecting-as-a-proxy-user-via-connection-string)

Oracle documentation of [Proxy Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/odpnt/featConnecting.html#GUID-EC0754B1-367C-409D-A495-AE5BA9634B65) with Oracle Data Provider for .NET